# DllImport in my web application

Tags: c#, dllimport

I made a web application that use a `DllImport` to use a specific printer in my application. The printer `DLL` are in my `System32`. If I put myweb application in my web server, this `DllImport` will search for this `Dll` in my server or in the client ?

If the answer is in the client, how can I made to search this `Dll` in the client ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLL will be searched for on the Server, not the client.

You should also know that anything printed through the .NET code will be printed on the Server side as that's where all of the .NET code executes.

Comment: This explain why in localhost works fine, but when I put the application at the webserver, doesn't.

Comment: Has a way to do a DllImport to the client side ?

Comment: No. You'll have to figure out a way to get the document to the client side and use some kind of client side code to print the document.